# Docker container is not able to populate SECRET_TOKEN env variable for rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker

I am following https://semaphoreci.com/community/tutorials/dockerizing-a-ruby-on-rails-application to create a sample rails app from rails docker image. Idea is to dockerize a rail application. I have creates a .drkiq.env file in rails app root directory in docker's recommended format of KEY=value as given below

```
SECRET_TOKEN=asecuretokenwouldnormallygohere
WORKER_PROCESSES=1
LISTEN_ON=0.0.0.0:8000
DATABASE_URL=postgresql://drkiq:yourpassword@postgres:5432/drkiq?encoding=utf8&pool=5&timeout=5000
CACHE_URL=redis://redis:6379/0
JOB_WORKER_URL=redis://redis:6379/0
```

I am reading the environment file from my docker=compose.yml file (also residing in app root directory)

```
postgres:
  image: postgres:9.4.5
  environment:
    POSTGRES_USER: drkiq
    POSTGRES_PASSWORD: yourpassword
  ports:
    - '5432:5432'
  volumes:
    - drkiq-postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data

redis:
  image: redis:3.0.5
  ports:
    - '6379:6379'
  volumes:
    - drkiq-redis:/var/lib/redis/data

drkiq:
  build: .
  links:
    - postgres
    - redis
  volumes:
    - .:/drkiq
  ports:
    - '8000:8000'
 env_file:
    - .drkiq.env

sidekiq:
  build: .
  command: bundle exec sidekiq -C config/sidekiq.yml
  links:
    - postgres
    - redis
  volumes:
    - .:/drkiq
  env_file:
    - .drkiq.env
```

Inside my Dockerfile (residing in app root directory), I am running unicorn server

```
CMD bundle exec unicorn -c config/unicorn.rb
```

But when I run command

```
docker-compose up
```

and access http://my-host:8000/ It gives me "RuntimeError at /
Missing `secret_token` and `secret_key_base` for 'development' environment, set these values in `config/secrets.yml`" error. I am not sure what I am missing here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My bad. in my rails app I was actually looking for SECRET_KEY_BASE variable but in .drkiq.env file (as pasted above) I was setting SECRET_TOKEN. I replaced SECRET_TOKEN with SECRET_KEY_BASE and restarted docker and every thing was shiny and warm.